# Permission Level which doesn't allow renaming file in document library

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, 2016, rename

I need to remove the **delete and rename option** from advanced options for files in document library. I copied **Contribute Permission Level** and removed Delete File option and it successfully removed the Delete Option, but I can't find way to remove also the **Rename Option.** Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no single permission to control Rename option.

But, if the user has Contribution permissions without Delete Item permission, he will get Access Denied when edit the name of the file. Contributor users are not able to rename items in SharePoint if the Delete permission level is removed from the Contributors group.

It is by design and is mentioned in this official article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2505742/contributor-users-are-not-able-to-rename-items-in-sharepoint-if-the-de.

Per my testing, it also affects in SharePoint 2016.

**Update:**

When user who has Contribution without Delete permission is trying to save the change of file name, he gets Access Denied:

[image]

Comment: As I said, in my answer :)

Comment: I uploaded a picture with the copied Contribute Permission Level and removed delete items permission. The result is the same. Rename option still remains.

Comment: User can still can access "Edit Properties" to edit properties for the file. But when he tries to change the file name, he will get Access Denied. Check my screenshot in the reply.

Comment: Yes, looks like it will stay like this.  Request was this option to be removed, but they will need to accept that the rename option will be there but not doable.

Answer (score 6):

The rename option comes with the permission to delete items. If you remove the delete item permission, the rename option will also be removed from the [...] menu.

1. Create a custom permission that is a copy of Contribute permission level
2. Remove the permission to delete items
3. Save you custom permission level as "Contribute without delete"
4. Assign the member group of the site with your new "Contribute without delete" permission, and remove edit and/or contribute from the member group.
5. Test to see that it actually works

Comment: But if you remove edit permissions, they won't be able to upload or edit documents, no? What am I not getting?

Comment: You add contribute without delete permission (custom). User can add, edit, update but not delete (nor rename) docs.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to use Jquery to remove that option as i dont think there is any default option to do that