# Rename Documents without Delete Permissions - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, administration, custom-permission-level

We have a group that wants to allow users to rename files in a library but not be able to delete files.

Does anyone know the right settings for permission levels to enable this restriction?

This is SharePoint/O365 Online.

Comment: We have implemented this at a docset level but users with the custom contribute-no delete permissions applied are still unable to rename files: do the customer site permissions behave differently for docsets?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom permission by

1. Go to Site Settings
2. Select Site Permission
3. Select Permission Levels (from ribbon)
4. Click Contribute (since this is the closest one based on your requirement)
5. At the bottom, click 'Copy Permission Level'
6. Give it a name, description then remove check from 'Delete Items'
7. Click Create to Finish
8. Update the SharePoint Group's Permission to this new Custom permission level

Answer (score 0):

This is a default behavior in SharePoint. You need Delete permissions on items/files if you want to rename those. So, you will have to allow delete permissions if you want users to rename the documents in SharePoint document library.

This behavior corresponds to user's experience on Windows file servers or when users access to a SharePoint web server through Explorer View (WebDAV HTTP protocol extension).

You can find this information in Microsoft official page at: [Contributor users are not able to rename items in SharePoint if the Delete permission level is removed from the Contributors group](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/dc4330c0-c1bd-59bd-ba4f-c1c0049809bb)

Also, check below similar threads for more information:

1. [Why delete permission is required to rename a document in SP Document Library?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/why-delete-permission-is-required-to-rename-a-document-in-sp/m-p/45902)
2. [Rename a file - Without Delete permission](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/298538/rename-a-file-without-delete-permission)
3. [Permission Level which doesn't allow renaming file in document library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255781/permission-level-which-doesnt-allow-renaming-file-in-document-library)

**Similar thread**: [Can we allow users to rename files but prevent them from deleting those files inside SharePoint online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/308710/can-we-allow-users-to-rename-files-but-prevent-them-from-deleting-those-files-in)